# getStaticProps error on build with Contentful in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

I have an issue with NextJS and Contentful, everything is OK on local, but when trying to build I have errors. It might be a dummy issue but cannot figure it out (the issue is somewhere here because when I comment my SingleRealisation component everything works just fine...

Someone has an idea of what's wrong ?

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/realisations/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fields')
```

```js
const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
});

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'realisations',
    });

    const paths = res.items.map((item) => {
        return {
            params: { slug: item.fields.slug },
        };
    });

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true,
    };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'realisations',
        'fields.slug': params.slug,
    });

    return {
        props: {
            realisation: res.items[0],
        },
        revalidate: 1,
    };
};

const Realisation = ({ realisation }) => {
    console.log(realisation);
    return (
        <Wrapper
            url="https://www.graphandco.com"
            title={`${realisation.fields.title} | Graph and Co`}
            description={`Présentation du site ${realisation.fields.title}`}
            twitter="graphandco"
            imageUrl="https://sites.graphandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/logo.png"
            imageAlt="Graph and Co"
            background="linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(205deg 44% 21%), rgb(12, 16, 18))"
        >
            <SingleRealisation realisation={realisation} />
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

export default Realisation;
```

Comment: Make sure `res.items[0]` is valid (return a 404 page if not) before returning it in `getStaticProps`.

Comment: Thanks for feeding back, do I have to check if "res" is valid in my ```getStaticProps``` function ? Don't really know how to return a 404 instead. And I have no issue on my page which is querying all the datas. The issue is just for the single data page...

Comment: Yes, I would add a check like `if(!res?.items?.[0]) { return { notFound: true } }` before returning the `props` in `getStaticProps`. That will return a 404 page for the failing path, preventing the build error to occur.

Comment: In fact it did not solve the issue, but made me think that I should check the props before returning the component. And it worked !! But I kept your code, I think it is good to check also in the ```getStaticProps```. Thank you so much for showing me the way !! ```const Realisation = ({ realisation }) => {
    if (realisation) {
        return (
                <SingleRealisation realisation={realisation} />
        );
    }
    return <Custom404 />
};```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the props before returning the component solved the issue :

````
const client = createClient({
    space: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
});

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'realisations',
    });

    const paths = res.items.map((item) => {
        return {
            params: { slug: item.fields.slug },
        };
    });

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true,
    };
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const res = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'realisations',
        'fields.slug': params.slug,
    });

    if (!res?.items?.[0]) {
        return { notFound: true };
    }

    return {
        props: {
            realisation: res.items[0] || {},
        },
        revalidate: 1,
    };
};

const Realisation = ({ realisation }) => {
    if (realisation) {
        return (
            <Wrapper
                url="https://www.graphandco.com"
                title={`${realisation.fields.title ? realisation.fields.title : ''} | Graph and Co`}
                description={`Présentation du site ${realisation.fields.title ? realisation.fields.title : ''}`}
                twitter="graphandco"
                imageUrl="https://sites.graphandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/logo.png"
                imageAlt="Graph and Co"
                background="linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(205deg 44% 21%), rgb(12, 16, 18))"
            >
                <SingleRealisation realisation={realisation} />
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
    return <Custom404 />;
};```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).